# Theorem: formulation of uniqueness?

Tags: functions, soft-question, group-isomorphism, article-writing

I wonder which formulation of the following statement is preferable? I understand they are equivalent, but which is considered clearer?

1. > Suppose $A,B\geq2$ are natural numbers. If the groups $G_A$ and $G_B$ are isomorphic, then $A=B$.
2. > The function $A\mapsto G_A$ is injective on the natural numbers $\geq2$.
3. > Suppose $A,B\geq2$ are two distinct natural numbers. Then $G_A$ and $G_B$ are not isomorphic.

We of course define $G_A$ earlier in the works.

I don't quite like 2 as it's over-formalistic. But 1 and 3 are quite equivalent. I personally like 3 more, but my colleague somehow prefers 1. Is there any good reason to choose one or the other?

Comment: I can't add to your reasoning, but I'll comment that I'm of the same opinion as you, that 3 is more nicely formulated. However, and especially if your audience is undergraduate students, have you thought of being even less rigorous? Along the lines of "if $A,B$ are distinct, then so are $G_A,G_B$" (leaving up to your audience what "distinct" means in this context).

Comment: @JonathanY. It's for a scientific paper, and I shall be rigorous about the "isomorphism" part. That's actually one other reason why 2 is bad.

Comment: In that case, you can't go wrong. As this is a soft question, I'll add my personal inclination: "proper behavior precedes the Torah"; let your coauthors have their way unless you materially object.

Comment: I actually prefer $2$

Comment: “The groups $G_n$, defined for natural $n\ge2$, are pairwise not isomorphic.”

Comment: (2) isn't equivalent to the others: $A \to G_A$ could potentially be injective, but still have $G_A \cong G_B$ when $A \neq B$.

Comment: "The groups $G_A$ and $G_B$ are non-isomorphic whenever $A \neq B$."

Answer (score 0):

This similar to the two definitions of injective function.

I think that the third is more elegant, because there is no "if" and the statement is more direct, but the seceond is seems to be more confortable to use.

The way of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) is good: you can state your preferable statement and put the second right after that.

Comment: In number 3, there is an “if”, it's just concealed.

Comment: You right in the overall, but that way of thinking you get more if-s: 1. If A is number".  2.If  B are  number  3. If $ A \geq 2 $ 4. If $ B \geq 2 $. 
I agree that mathematically there is no different.